# Getting Wing IDE to stop catching the exceptions that wxPython catches

Tags: python, wxpython, wing-ide

I started using Wing IDE and it's great. I'm building a wxPython app, and I noticed that Wing IDE catches exceptions that are usually caught by wxPython and not really raised. This is usually useful, but I would like to disable this behavior occasionally. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Ignore this exception location` check box in the window where the exception is reported in wing, or you could explicitly silence that specific exception in you code with a `try except` block.